# interactive big 2D point cloud data visualization on map with python

Tags: bigdata, visualization, point-clouds, holoviews, datashader

I have a 2D point cloud data time series. The shape of the data is [N, T]. N is a big number（millions) and T is the number of 2D point cloud images and generally less than 300. I also have the coordinates of these N points with shape of [N, 2] (the longitudes and the latitudes). I want to interactively visualize these data in a map.

Specifically, I want:
1.) interactively zoom in or out to show both the specific region and the big picture;
2.) I can click one point and plot the time series of this point;
3.) I can switch which image to be shown among the T images.

I know it is impossible and unnecessary to plot that much of points. A dynamic aggregation and rasterization would be a better choice. https://egms.land.copernicus.eu/ is a very good example. It meets all of my requirement. It only shows all points when zoom into a small region. Otherwise, only a small number of points are shown. It could be the reason of its efficiency.

The only similar technique I found in Python ecosystem is Holoviews+Datashader. But I find it is still not very efficient. The reason could be that datashader rasterizes the point cloud on the fly, but that website rasterizes the point cloud previously and only on several specific zoom level.

I want to know if there are any python packages that can visualize such large dataset efficiently, or if there are any better ways to utilize holoviews and datashader. Thanks!

Comment: You can use Datashader to pre-render tiles the same as for that EGMS example. See https://github.com/holoviz/datashader/blob/main/examples/tiling.ipynb , but we haven't documented it very well and the process is fairly clunky. For our purposes we prefer to use the dynamic rendering, but if someone has applications for the static pre-rendered tiles, we'd love for someone to improve this process and document it better.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your information. This tiling module doesn't exactly meet my need, so I am looking into the source code to see if I can do such tiling by myself. I get some questions. 1. Why you need to define supertiles and subtiles, is it for performance? 2. I want to have hover functions discussed in https://github.com/holoviz/datashader/issues/1126 . Mr. Ian Thomas provides a way to do it by adding a new index column to the dataframe.  Are there any better way to do it now?